# Are Rally WsapiDataStores passed by reference?

Tags: rally

I am trying to create a portfolio item report that utilizes a Rally.ui.grid.Grid for some attributes information and an Ext.panel.Panel for the description.  Because I want to match this information 1-to-1, I am paging through a data query.  Everything works to show me the data formatted as I want but the data from the final call fill every grid (3rd page fills grids 1-3).  This makes me wonder if the store is passed into the grid by reference and how can I change that so it is unique for every grid.  Below is the code snippet:

```
_loadScopeDetails: function() {    
    Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
        autoLoad: true,
        pageSize: 1,    // Load 1 page at a time
        limit: 1,       // Limit to 1

        model: 'PortfolioItem/MMF',
        context: MyApp.globalContext,

        fetch: ['Parent',
                'Project',
                'Name',
                'InvestmentCategory',
                'PlannedStartDate',
                'PlannedEndDate',
                'Description'
                ],

        filters: [
                {
                    property: 'Parent.Name',
                    operator: 'Contains',
                    value: MyApp.selectedEpicName
                }
            ],

        sorters: {
            property: 'Rank',
            direction: 'ASC'
        },

        listeners: {
            load: function( store, records ) {
                MyApp._buildScopeDetails( store, records );

                // Load the next until all pages are loaded
                if ( store.currentPage < store.totalCount )
                {
                   store.loadPage( store.currentPage+1 );
                }
                else
                {
                    var index = 0;
                    for (index=0; index< store.totalCount; index++ ){
                        MyApp.scopePane.add(MyApp.scopeDetails[index]);
                        MyApp.scopePane.add(MyApp.scopeDescription[index] );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
},

_buildScopeDetails: function(myStore, records) {
    // Filter off the epic from the scope title
    var epicTitle = MyApp.selectedEpicName + ': ';
    var title = records[0].data.Name;
    if ( 0 === title.indexOf( epicTitle ) ) {
        title = title.substr( epicTitle.length );
    }

    MyApp.scopeDetails.push( Ext.create('Rally.ui.grid.Grid', {
        store: myStore,  // This seems to be referenced in all grids!?!?!
        title: '<a href=\'' + Rally.nav.Manager.getDetailUrl( records[0] ) + '\'>' + title + '</a>',
        border: 1,
        columnCfgs: [
            'Name',
            {dataIndex: 'c_SAPProjectNumber', text:'SAP #'},
            'InvestmentCategory',
            'PlannedStartDate',
            'PlannedEndDate',
            'Project'
        ],
        showPagingToolbar: false            
    }) );

    MyApp.scopeDescription.push( Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        width: '100%',
        html: '<p>' + records[0].data.Description + '</p>',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    }) );
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what is happening is the model being used for the grid is changing. So when the model changes, the grid updates to show that info.

To get all of the info on one graph, you'll probably need to one of two things.

1. Make a store and save the records you want to display to it.  Use that store for your table.
2. Have the WsapiDataStore fetch all entries in one go, and parse through them to get the data you want.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I changed it to be recursive and use a page counter which created new datastores to use within the grids.